# How can I get `pip install`'s download progress?

Tags: download, installation, pip, verbosity

Using `pip install` on some large package doesn't show any progress report while downloading.

Using the `-v, --verbose` option doesn't do it and [there doesn't seem to be any other relevant option](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html).

Answer (score 22):

At least pip9 has `-v` option which prints debug msg during installation of the package.

```bash
$ pip --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
pip 9.0.1
```

Help:

```bash
$ pip install --help
..
..
-v, --verbose               Give more output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times.
```

Usage:

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt -vvv
```

Comment: That doesn't give the percent progress!!

Answer (score 4):

Seems that `pip` needs a `--log` argument to echo to the screen, e.g.:

```
$ pip -v --log /tmp/pip.log install $python_pkg --upgrade
```